# Cordova iOS FingerPrint Authentication : Sending User Credentials to Server

Tags: ios, cordova, authentication, touch-id

I understand how to use the iOS fingerprint authentication mechanism, but I am doubtful about where and how to store the user credentials. Once the fingerprint is authenticated, I need to send the user details to the server. Since the user did not type it in anywhere, I assume I will have to store it when the user types it in the first time. Where do I store these credentials securely? Is iOS KeyChain the solution for this?

Comment: Yes, the keychain is the solution.  You can use the fingerprint authentication to unlock the keychain item.  You can also set a property on the keychain item such that it is deleted if a new fingerprint is added.

Comment: @Paulw11 Authentication of id and password for every login is mandatory in my application. so does this mean that i have to store the user's id and password in the keychain and on successful fingerprint authentication, send the id and password to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i implemented touch id for my app.

```
 1. check if fingerprint is enabled : user credentials  is stored in keychain
 2. if fingerprint is enabled, prompt for fingerprint touch
 3. else show login screen
 4. if user checks "enable fingerprint" checkbox and logs in, store username and password in keychain 
 5. else login as normal
```

I used the following plugin :
https://github.com/sjhoeksma/cordova-plugin-keychain-touch-id